# slow wifi connection in ubuntu 21.04

Tags: internet

I've installed ubuntu 21.04 on my laptop, but recently I have faced the problem of a slow and unstable wifi connection
I'm here to ask if anybody had this issue and could fix it?\

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 10
       serial: f0:79:59:85:a1:f3
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.11.0-16-generic firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:18 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7204000-f7204fff memory:f7200000-f7203fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 01
       serial: 40:e2:30:a4:06:05
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=5.11.0-16-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.43.93 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:19 memory:f7100000-f717ffff memory:f7180000-f718ffff
```

this is what I get as an output for `sudo lshw -c network`

Comment: The linked Q&A is only applicable to Intel cards. Please first reboot your router and then check if you have the recommended settings: WPA2-AES

Comment: There isn’t enough information here to answer the question in any real way. Could you update your question to include the output of `sudo lshw -c network` as well as what you mean by “slow”. This will make it easier to offer specific support 

Comment: @matigo thanks for your comment, I updated the question as you said
I don't know what other information should I provide for this question so I appreciate it if you help me with that.

Answer (score 1):

This particular Atheros wireless card seems to have "a history" with various Linux distributions. Let's first do a test and, if you find that the network speed is satisfactory, later update a configuration file.

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Remove the current Atheros driver:

   ```
   sudo modprobe -r ath9k
   ```
2. Restore the Atheros driver with an additional flag:

   ```
   sudo modprobe ath9k nohwcrypt=1
   ```
3. Test your WiFi by using the machine for a few hours

If everything proves to be good, then you can modify a configuration file to ensure `nohwcrypt` is properly set after every reboot.

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Create/Edit the `/etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf` file using your preferred text editor and `sudo`:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
   ```
2. Add the following line to the end of the file:

   ```
   options ath9k nohwcrypt=1
   ```
3. Save the file

Now, when you reboot, the `nohwcrypt` flag will be correctly set for you.